# Exception won't get caught

Tags: c#, winforms

I have custom `Paint` handler that does stuff with image

```
void MainForm_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e) {
    try {
        int x = (Width - img.Width) / 2;
        int y = (Height - img.Height) / 2;
        e.Graphics.Clear(BackColor);
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(img, x, y);
    } catch { }
}
```

`try-catch` there because `img` get changed every 10 ms using `System.Timers.Timer`
Just for example, it just draw one more pixel in a row.

```
void tick(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e) {
    timer.Stop();
    try {
        img?.Dispose();
        img = new Bitmap(100, 100);
        Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(img);
        for (int i = 0; i < progress; i++)
            g.FillRectangle(Brushes.Black, i % 100, (int)Math.Floor(i / 100f), 1, 1);
        if (++progress == 10000)
            progress = 0;
        g.Dispose();
        Invalidate();
    } catch {}
    timer.Start();
}
```

So sometimes form gets invalidated and `Paint` event raises. It might happen when `tick` is working on new image, so `img` might be disposed. It's okay to skip `Paint` in such situation, but the `catch` code just won't get called, so  exception occures at quite odd location somewhere around `progress==3500`. Or crashes completely (if not debugging)
[image]
*.NET 4.6.1 (Project 4.0), Win7 x64, VS 2015*

Comment: Never fix a bug in your code with try/catch-em-all, *especially* a threading bug.  Use the `lock` keyword so your code cannot paint at the exact same time you are modifying the image.

Comment: _"If I continue through this exception, everything is fine"_ -- that contradicts your statement that if you are not debugging, the process "crashes" (i.e. terminates with an error). In any case, the correct solution is to fix the code so that the exception isn't thrown. Please provide a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces the problem if you want help with that.

Comment: @PeterDuniho Sorry. While writing this question I did few changes to the code and forgot to edit question properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somebody already mentioned it in the comments and should have probably made it an answer but you should use the lock keyword to lock the image object so another thread cannot attempt to change it at the same time.

You can read more here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz.aspx